# Display sidebar in left side

Tags: magento2, sidebar

I want to display sidebar in left side.
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: is this your custom module ?

Comment: This is your category page?

Comment: yes, this is my category page

Answer (score 0):

you have to change inside layout xml file,

if you want to display product details page 2column left then change file is catalog_category_view.xml or your custom layout file set `layout="scolumns-left"`

set layout value layout="2columns-left" inside  node

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Comment: i already set layout="2columns-left" but it showing at bottom

Comment: Your Custom layout Display in the bottom? this Page category page?